# How do I update the projection of a choropleth map in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly-python, choropleth

I have a choropleth map with a projection type of `albers usa`. I want to dynamically zoom the map based on a state selection to just be focused around a single state on the map. I tried to use the `lataxis` and `lonaxis` properties, but I must be doing something wrong, as I can't get them to work at all. Here is what I tried:

```
self.states_plot.layout = dict(
  title = None,
  dragmode=False,
  paper_bgcolor='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
  plot_bgcolor='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
  geo=dict(
    showframe=False,
    showcoastlines=False,
    projection_type='equirectangular',
    scope='usa',
    projection= dict(
      type='albers usa',
      lonaxis=dict(
        range=[-125.756267, -116.439860]
      ),
      lataxis=dict(
        range=[49.357767, 45.495262]
      )
    ),
    bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    lonaxis=dict(
      range=[-125.756267, -116.439860]
    ),
    lataxis=dict(
      range=[49.357767, 45.495262]
    )
  ),
  margin= dict(
    l= 0,
    r= 0,
    b= 0,
    t= 0,
    pad= 0
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. The problem was that I wasn't setting the `geo.center.lat` and `geo.center.lon`